# Make siunitx use (locally) a font selected via mathastext

Tags: fonts, siunitx, mathastext

I want to change locally a font also for math text I can use the `mathastext` package. However `siunitx` doesn't seem to respect this as showed in the following example (with the augie font). So how can I make siunitx to use the augie font as well in my example?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  detect-all,
  detect-inline-family=math,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  detect-display-math=true
}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[subdued]{mathastext}
\MTfamily{augie}
\Mathastext[augie]


\begin{document}

{
\MTversion{augie}
This is some text and some math:
\begin{equation*}
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \Delta x_i
\end{equation*}
And here some numbers
\begin{equation*}
5\cdot 3 = 15
\end{equation*}
And now  with siunitx:
\begin{equation*}
\SI{5}{\m}\cdot \SI{3}{\m} = \SI{15}{\m\squared}
\end{equation*}  
}


The augie font should be applied only locally. 

This is some text and some math:
\begin{equation*}
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \Delta x_i
\end{equation*}
And here some numbers
\begin{equation*}
5\cdot 3 = 15
\end{equation*}
And now  with siunitx:
\begin{equation*}
\SI{5}{\m}\cdot \SI{3}{\m} = \SI{15}{\m\squared}
\end{equation*}  



\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Try `\begin{equation*}
5 \si{\m}\cdot 3 \si{\m} = 15 \si{\m\squared}
\end{equation*} `

Comment: @ferahfeza Thanks, but that doesn't work for be because I need siunitx in particular to automatically round numbers. Also this doesn't print the units in augie as well.